# Scilab Image Processing Toolboxes .How to pass 3 dimensional matrix from C++ code to scilab console?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on implementing Image Processing Toolbox in Scilab .For that i am implementing Opencv functions in Scilab through C++ using functions defined in Scilab API "api_scilab.h". Problem which i am facing is that i am unable to return 3 Dimensional Matrix (which is returned by opencv function) through my C++ code to Scilab console.Solution which i found for this problem is that i am converting 3 Dimensional Matrix to 1 Dimensional Matrix and then return it and convert 1 Dimensional Matrix back to 3 Dimensional Matrix whenever required.
I want to ask is there any function in Scilab API "api_scilab.h" by which i can directly return or pass 3 Dimensional matrix as argument .
Thank you in advance